# Java jbutton in an arraylist, how can i know which one is clicked

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jbutton, actionlistener

I have two arraylists with the same size, one for JButton, one for JTextField. When clicking the button, the corresponding textfield should be updated. How can I realize that?

p.s. the number of jcomponents pairs (jbutton + jtextfield) are not fixed. They are designed  to be added or removed by the user. However, they have to be in the fixed order.

```
    ArrayList<JButton> buttonList = new ArrayList<JButton>();
    ArrayList<JTextField> textFieldList = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

    private JButton createButton(){
    JButton button = new JButton("Choose File");
    buttonList.add(button);
    button.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    textField = textFieldList.get(i)
                    textField.setText("show updats");
                }
            }       
    );      
    return button;
}
```

How can I know the index "i" in the JButton ArrayList?

Comment: do a for loop. Ex: for(int i =0; i < buttonList.size(); i++) { buttonList.getButtonAtIndex(i); } PS: not actual code, just a reference to show you how to find it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`ActionEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html) has a [source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29), which will be the `JButton` that is firing the event.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    int i = buttonList.indexOf(event.getSource());
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will Vote Up after I get enough reputation :)